# How to clear a value on page load for derbyjs

Tags: derbyjs

Just out of curiosity if I have a chat application with an unread message counter...

How do I reset that counter?

Simply put, when User A writes a message, B increments there unread counter. When B is on the message page, I would like to reset that counter each refresh of the messages (it is running on subscribe).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was pretty simple.

You can write the following code in your html:

```
{{yourMethodName();}}
```

Then in your server you write some code:

```
app.proto.yourMethodName = function(){
  //Clear data
  this.model.del("yourdata.count");
  //similar to: this.model.set("yourdata.count",0);
}
```

Super simple.... Updated based off of Aleksey

Answer (score 1):

or `this.model.del("yourdata.count");`